# How to provide SSH access on a multi tenancy (Docker) container environment

Tags: ssh, docker

I run a server with 300 web apps on it for unique clients. Each web app has it's own Nginx/Apache container, and it's own PHP-FPM application container.  All containers are behind HAProxy which is performing domain vhost public IP (one IP shared between all containers) proxying to the per user Apache/Nginx container.

Users need access via SSH to their containers so they can manage their files by SFTP, and run commands on the shell via bash, php, git etc (the php-fpm container has git installed).

How do I give remote ssh access to 300+ application containers?  Ideally a centralised sshd container which will attach another container's shell based on username - is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The single SSH container approach will rely on pre-mounting all data volumes onto the single SSH container. So to maintain user separation you'd need to rely on data volumes from different users to have different UID owners, which will likely means that each service container will need to run with a different UID inside - and this will negate most of the simpleness gains you get from running in name-spaced containers in the first place...

The alternative of running multiple SSHd instances (either inside the service container or as a sidecar container) would be problematic for scaling.

Another alternative is using port mapping - assign each client a port for their SSH access, and set up SystemD socket services to socket-activate the SSHd service for each customer on demand. You can either expose each port directly outside the firewall and teach customers to use non-standard ports in their SSH configurations (not recommended) - or use HAProxy to front-end SSH over TLS using SNI and domain-name-to-port mapping to give domain-name based access to the socket-activated SSH servers. [This article might start you on your way](https://julian.pawlowski.me/geeking-out-with-haproxy-on-pfsense-the-ultimate/). This still requires you to teach customers about SSH over TLS, but that might be more sane than to maintain a domain name port mapping in customers' heads...